# CSV formatting in rows and columns

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

I'm using the following code for converting my json file into csv:

```
import csv
import sys

txt_file = r"myfile.txt"
csv_file = r"out.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = ',')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

My output turns out to be formatted in a single row, and I want field with the tag "name" stores all the name in a single column not in extended rows.

How else can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought have you tried a semicolon ; as the delimiter. I know you have csv indicated, but I recall seeing somewhere a semicolon will work.

Comment: I think semicolon will only apply if we deal with only columns, I'm trying to gather all names under the "name" field instead of having separate columns for each name